# Ordering in scala

Tags: scala

I learn

> Ordering

from this [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/math/Ordering.html).

And I tried the code below by my self:

```
val pairs = Array(("a", 5, 2), ("c", 3, 1), ("b", 1, 3))
Sorting.quickSort(pairs)(Ordering[(Int, String)].on[(String, Int, Int)]((_._3,_.1))
```

However, there is an error says that:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch;  found   : (String, Int, Int)  required: String
- ')' expected but double literal found.
- missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2._3)
```

May I know how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here: `((_._3,_.1))`

You need a function that takes a single `(String, Int, Int)` and returns a `(Int, String)`. You're also missing the closing `)` for that line.

This will do it for you: `(x=>(x._3,x._1))`  Notice that `x` represents the input tuple (triple) and can then be indexed with `._1`, `._2`, and `._3`.

You could also do it like this, `{case (a,b,c)=>(c,a)}`, which uses pattern matching to name all the elements of the input tuple so they can be easily referenced without indexing.

Comment: Can you give the complete answer as I am new to scala? thanks

Comment: Please make sure you have read related threads:http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/686/collections/2262/sort-a-list#t=201612090848077089488.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your request. I pointed out exactly what code to remove, suggested what you can replace it with, and tried to explain how the replacement code works.  What parts of that need further clarification?

Comment: Underscores are treated positionally. First underscore refers to the first function parameter etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I can write correct one, but I am not sure what does ordering.on and odering.by mean?e.g.  Sorting.quickSort(pairs)(Ordering[(Int, String)].on[(String, Int, Int)]((x=>(x._3,x._1))))

Sorting.quickSort(pairs)(Ordering.by[(String, Int, Int), Int](_._2))